# Почему в список попадает посторонний элемент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я решал задачу, текст которой выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой код:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.readline()

row_max = []
l_max = 0

def pie(start):
    row = [s[start]]
    for j in range(start+1, len(s)):
        if row[-1] <= s[j]:
            row.append(s[j])
            if len(Counter(row)) > 3:
                return
            elif len(Counter(row)) == 3:
                global l_max
                global row_max
                if len(row) > l_max:
                    l_max = len(row)
                    row_max = row
                    print(row_max)
        else:
            return

for i in range(1, len(s)):
    pie(i)

print('-----')
print(row_max)
```

**text.txt:**

```
AABBAABBCCDDDEFFGF
```

В решении использовал глобальные переменные. Я знаю, что это плохо. Но эта задача из ЕГЭ, и если я буду делать акцент на правильности кода, то на экзамене мне просто не хватит времени.

Вывод в консоль:

```
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']

['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C']

['B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'] 

-----

['B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E']
```

**Проблема** в том, что все изменения переменной `row_max` представлены в первых трех строчках вывода, поэтому конечная длина этого списка должна быть равна 7. Но в самом конце программы значение `row_max` почему-то изменяется - в список добавляется строка 'Е'. Я не могу понять причину этого изменения. Допускаю, что делаю очень глупую ошибку. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он идет в след за последней "D":

```py
for j in range(start+1, len(s)):
    if row[-1] <= s[j]:
        row.append(s[j])
.
.
.

   row_max = row
```

Comment: Да, но, я считаю, что эта часть кода не должна выполняться. Количество разных символов в списке становится больше трех, а это контролирует условие `if len(Counter(row)) > 3: return`

Comment: вы же взяли D вторую по счету, добавили третью, после чего добавили Е, после чего получили условие на выход, тк символов стало 4, но уже после добавления Е

Comment: Да, но 'E' должна была добавиться в список 'row'. Список 'row_max' должен был остаться без изменений. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @MAXIM045, когда вы пишите `row_max = row` то вы не копируете содержимое списка, а, по сути делаете алиас исходного массива под другим именем. Т.е содержимое обоих списков в любой момент времени одинаково (ибо обе переменные ссылаются на одни и те же данные). Сами можете попробовать после такого присваивания списка списку, добавить в один из них элемент и посмотреть в другой список, где вы этот новый элемент также обнаружите. Чтобы сделать копию списка, пишите, например, так: `row_max = row[:]`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я понял ошибку